# guardar todos los datos de un recyclerview de edittexts con un solo boton

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview

tengo un recyclerview formado por edittexts para introducir datos. De manera que con cada edit text tengo tambien un boton "guardar" para que cuando se pulse se guarde el valor del edittext correspondiente en un arraylist. Luego dicho arraylist (que esta definido dentro de un adaptador) lo leo desde el mainactivity utilizando el metodo getInput() del adaptador, que me devuelve el array con los datos del edittext. Pero el problema es que necesito un boton para cada edittext del recycler, y queria hacerlo todo junto con un solo boton y no encuentro la manera ya que en el adaptador no se puede poner un boton independiente sino que hay que poner un boton por cada item. Este es el codigo:

mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> als = new ArrayList();
    public RecyclerView recycler;
    public Button boton;
    public ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boton= findViewById(R.id.boton);
        recycler= findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        for(int i=0; i<7;i++)
        {
            als.add("Hola");

        }
        adapter a= new adapter(als);
        recycler.setAdapter(a);

        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                input=a.getInput();
                for(String s: input)
                {
                    Log.i("hola",s);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mostrar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

adapter:

```
public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.ViewHolder>{

    public ArrayList<String> listDatos;
    public static ArrayList<String> input;

    public adapter(ArrayList<String> listDatos) {
        this.listDatos = listDatos;
        this.input= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlist,null,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nombre.setText(listDatos.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listDatos.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getInput()
    {
        return input;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText nombre;
        Button guardar;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nombre=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
            guardar= itemView.findViewById(R.id.guardar);
            guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    input.add(nombre.getText().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

itemlist.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/nombre"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/guardar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guardar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

clase bien:

```
public class Bien {
    private String nombre;
    private double valor;

    public Bien(String nombre, double valor) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedo recomendarte dos opciones.

- No es muy recomendable que tengas edit text en un recycler view porque te puede dar muchos problemas. Uno de ellos es el que tienes. Si tus EditText son estáticos, recomendaría que los agregues de manera estática y así eliminarías el recycler view. Me parece que con ello puedes solucionar el problema.
- En caso quieras persistir con el recycler view. La opción que veo es agregar un Watcher a cada editText y ese watcher es el que registra los cambios en tu edit text de manera dinámica. Asimismo, con esa idea ya no es necesario un botón "Guardar" porque todo se va realizar conforme se escribe en cada edit text. Pero en caso se desea continuar con el botón "botón guardar". Puedes tener una variable auxiliar donde guardes los cambios y si presionas "Guardar" los agregas, de caso contrario no( incluso puedes limpiar aquí tus variables auxiliares)

  ```
   guardar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       .....
       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
           // position debe ser la posición de tu edit text en el recycler view la cual debe coincidir con la position en tu array
           input.set(position, editable.toString());

       }
   });
  ```